# AJAX calls are failing with jqXHR Status 0

Tags: javascript, ajax

To display a particular content on Page we make AJAX call to one of the clients. Few of the AJAX calls are failing with jqXHR Status 0.

Few Pointers :

1. Client always catches exceptions and returns Status 200.
2. This AJAX call is only made on Mobile App.

On some research, we found that these could be the following reasons :

1. doing cross-site scripting (where access is denied)
2. requesting a URL that is unreachable (typo, DNS issues, etc)
3. the request is otherwise intercepted (check your ad blocker)
4. as above, if the request is interrupted (browser navigates away from the page)
5. if you have sent an AJAX call and a refresh of the browser was triggered before getting the AJAX response

Is there any other possible reason for jqXHR Status 0?
We have tried reproducing this but we were never able to reproduce. Is there any way to reproduce?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is nice to give pointers and your research, but if you need some help with your code, you will need to share your code. Please check [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more details.

Comment: Have you tried to capture the error message from the exception ? Usually it is more verbose than the error code is most of the time shows the actual reason for the issue.